# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tokenGetter' of undefined

Tags: angular

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'tokenGetter' of undefined

I am getting above error while calling http request

login component code

```
this.userData.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data;
    console.log('USER DATA : '+ this.user);
  });
```

user service code

```
public login(userData: User): Observable<User> {

console.log('USER DATA SERVICE');
return this.http.post<User>(`${this.apiUrl}/userlogin.php`, userData);
  // return this.http.get<User>(`${this.apiUrl}/userlogin.php?username=${username}&password=${password}`).pipe(
  //   catchError(this.handleError)
  // );
}
```

Comment: I am new to Angular so please help me out

Comment: `tokenGetter` is probably a part of auth0/angular2-jwt (it's a method in that package at least). You probably have a `TokenCheckHttpClientInterceptor` in your code that is being called before the post is actually being made. It appears that something inside it is not being initialized correctly (the base object is NULL) which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: thank you very much friend but now i am getting this error          Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/userlogin.php' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource                                                                                                i tried to add this code to php file but same error i am getting

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

Comment: I can't tell from your 2nd comment if those Headers are what's in your server configuration, or if it's in response to your preflight request. It seems like something is misconfigured on the server though even though those headers look okay.

Comment: code is working fine in browser and its giving me the result but if i am calling api from front-end its giving me error

Comment: THANK YOU FRIEND NOW MY PROBLEM RESOLVE SO THANKS AGAIN....